# Development, repository and deployment organization

Tags: deployment, repository, organization

I'm looking for your advice.

Initial situation:

- we (at the moment 5 developers, 1 quality guy/documentation, 1 projectmanagement/organization) plan to do a small startup
- we all earn our living with coding, but for better paid projects you'll have mostly no chance as one-man-show
- located somewhere mostly in europe
- we'll do clojure, php, perl, python and ruby development not only web apps
- we'll do c coding for machine control etc.
- all of use have different experience with editors, cvs and co.
- we don't want to reinvent the wheel

What's the best way to organize:

- the team's workflow?
- time logging for invoices=
- app staging -> developmen&repository / testing / deployment (own hosted and customer hosted systems)?
- creating documentation (I would like to use vimwiki, but not all of us use vim. Actually we think about LaTeX and graphviz)?
- Bug and issue tracking?
- everyone should be granted the most degree of freedom in using tools he knows and likes, without shooting ourselfs in the foot

Please let me know:

- where to find experience approved informations (Books, Tutorial, Best Practices, Urls, etc.)?
- what experiences (good&bad) did you made?
- exist professional courses which teach this topics?
- is Scrum worth a test (no one of us has experience with Scrum)?
- What do you think about timemangagement (e.g. Pomodoro etc.)?

I've read several posts on stackoverflow.com and superuser.com but up to now I did not get the puzzle...

I don't expect a out-of-the-box solution. I'm interested in your experiences and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking a general question, in spite of that, you should cast a glance at [software development process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process)